# Member reference base type 'elem *' is not a structure or union C++

Tags: c++

What's wrong with this code?
I really don't know. I'm beginner. Sorry for my english.

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct elem
{
    int wartosc;
    elem* nast;
    elem* poprz;
};

class ListaDwukierunkowa
{
protected:
    elem **lista;

public:
    ListaDwukierunkowa(elem** lista)
    {
        this->lista = lista;
    }

    void dodaj_elem(int do_dodania)
    {
        if (*lista == nullptr)
        {
            *lista = new elem;
            (*lista)->wartosc = do_dodania;
            (*lista)->nast = nullptr;
            (*lista)->poprz = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            elem *temp = *lista;
            while (temp->nast != nullptr)
            {
                temp = temp->nast;
            }
            temp->nast = new elem;
            temp->nast->wartosc = do_dodania;
            temp->nast->nast = nullptr;
            temp->nast->poprz = temp;
        }
    }

    void wyswietl_elem()
    {
        cout << endl;
        if (lista == nullptr)
        {
            cout << "Lista jest pusta" << endl;
        }
        while (lista != nullptr)
        {
            cout << "poprz: " <<  lista->poprz << " | ten: " << lista << " | war:" << lista->wartosc << " | nast:" << lista->nast << endl;
            lista = lista->nast;
        }
    }

    void usun_elem(int do_usun)
    {
        elem *temp = *lista;
        if (*lista == nullptr)
            return;

        while (temp->wartosc != do_usun)
        {
            temp = temp->nast;
            if (temp == nullptr)
                return;
        }

        if (temp->poprz)
            temp->poprz->nast = temp->nast;
        else
            *lista = temp->nast;

        if (temp->nast)
            temp->nast->poprz = temp->poprz;

        delete temp;
    }

    int liczba_elem()
    {
        int liczba = 0;
        while (lista != nullptr)
        {
            liczba += 1;
            lista = lista->nast;
        }
        return liczba;
    }

    int liczba_elem_o_war(int x)
    {
        int liczba = 0;
        while (lista != nullptr)
        {
            if (lista->wartosc == x)
            {
                liczba += 1;
            }
            lista = lista->nast;
        }
        return liczba;
    }

    bool czy_zawiera(int x)
    {
        bool czy = false;
        while (lista != nullptr)
        {
            if (lista->wartosc == x)
            {
                czy = true;
            }
            lista = lista->nast;
        }
        return czy;
    }

    void zwolnij_liste()
    {
        while (*lista != nullptr)
        {
            elem* nast = (*lista)->nast;
            delete *lista;
            *lista = nast;
        }
        *lista = nullptr;
    }
};




int main()
{
    ListaDwukierunkowa lista;

    lista.dodaj_elem(1);
    lista.wyswietl_elem();

//    dodaj_elem(&wsk, 12);
//    dodaj_elem(&wsk, 9);
//    dodaj_elem(&wsk, 8);
//    dodaj_elem(&wsk, 9);
//    dodaj_elem(&wsk, 9);
//    wyswietl_elem(wsk);
//    cout << liczba_elem(wsk) << endl;
//    cout << liczba_elem_o_war(wsk, 9) << endl;
//    cout << boolalpha << czy_zawiera(wsk, 12) << endl;
//    usun_elem(&wsk, 1);
//    wyswietl_elem(wsk);
//    zwolnij_liste(&wsk);

}
```

```
error: request for member 'poprz' in '*((ListaDwukierunkowa*)this)->ListaDwukierunkowa::lista', which is of pointer type 'elem*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
             cout << "poprz: " <<  lista->poprz << " | ten: " << lista << " | war:" << lista->wartosc << " | nast:" << lista->nast << endl;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBWbM.png)

---

image of errors,

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Explain your problem instead adding garbage to the question please.

Comment: Also,Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Even if you don't understand the message, it at least tells you that something is wrong about `lista->poprz`. There's also a "maybe you meant to" which may also be a clue.

Answer (score 2):

`lista` is of type `elem**`: a pointer to a pointer.

The `->` operator defererences *one* level of pointers. So `lista->poprz` is the same as (*lista).poprz.

In this case you need to dereference twice: `(*lista)->poprz`.

Note: I have not tried to understand *why* `lista` is a pointer to a pointer. It could be that you simply want `elem*` instead.